# Ansible Hostname Module - Adding OS Support

Tags: ansible

I'm attempting to use the Ansible Hostname module to update a hostname.  Works fine on CentOS, however throws a fatal error on CloudLinux operating system.

> msg: hostname module cannot be used on platform Linux (Cloudlinux)

CloudLinux is a drop in replacement for CentOS, so this module will work.  The error is a preflight check before the command is run, which is built into the module.

The question - how do i tell Ansible that 'CloudLinux' is a valid operating system for this module.

Obviously I could just use the command module to change the hostname - but I'd like to use the correct module if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Locate the code for the hostname module in your Ansible package (e.g. [`hostname.py` in Ansible 2.2.1](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/59c9a6d3c20e73641c430fdaa3f250c1ff431dcc/system/hostname.py));
2. Create a `library` folder in your Ansible project directory (the one containing the playbook) and copy the above file inside;
3. Locate [a section where distribution-specific settings are set](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/59c9a6d3c20e73641c430fdaa3f250c1ff431dcc/system/hostname.py#L509) within this file (for example `class CentOSHostname`, `class CentOSLinuxHostname`);
4. Add the following lines below, or above, or close to the CentOS:

   ```
   class CloudlinuxHostname(Hostname):
       platform = 'Linux'
       distribution = 'Cloudlinux'
       strategy_class = RedHatStrategy
   ```
5. Run the playbook.

Answer (score 0):

On newer version of ansible

```
# ansible --version
ansible 2.9.6

# ansible-doc -s hostname
- name: Manage hostname
  hostname:
      name:                  # (required) Name of the host
      use:                   # Which strategy to use to update the hostname. If not set we try to autodetect, but this can be problematic, specially with containers as they can
                               present misleading information.
```

**Sample playbook**

```
# cat host-setup.yml 
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
          - name: set hostname
            hostname:
                    name: "host.example.com"
                    use: systemd

# ansible-playbook -v  host-setup.yml
```

> ```
> # ansible-doc hostname
> > HOSTNAME    (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/modules/system/hostname.py)
>
>         Set system's hostname, supports most OSs/Distributions, including those using systemd. Note, this module does *NOT* modify
>         `/etc/hosts'. You need to modify it yourself using other modules like template or replace. Windows, HP-UX and AIX are not
> currently
>         supported.
>
>   * This module is maintained by The Ansible Community OPTIONS (= is
> mandatory):
>
> = name
>         Name of the host
>
>
> - use
>         Which strategy to use to update the hostname.
>         If not set we try to autodetect, but this can be problematic, specially with containers as they can present misleading information.
>         (Choices: generic, debian, sles, redhat, alpine, systemd, openrc, openbsd, solaris, freebsd)[Default: (null)]
>         version_added: 2.9
> ```